# showing the result of a jquery on a web form

Tags: jquery, forms, displaytag

Probably a very simple answer, but im only new to this.

I have a form that I am modifying from an existing form my company has. This form has a jquery that picks up the next availible claim number and submits it to my mysql database when the form is sumbitted.

I am trying to change this form to make it for purchase orders. The jquery function gets called anytime that the store selected changes (there is a list of 22 sites in a drop down box and it uses onchange='getClaimNumber()' ) so im assuming that number is picked up right at the beginning.

How can i make the form show this number once the store is chosen? Idealy the form should be able to be printed off showing the number and then submitted. I am happy to even have a button that calls the query and makes it display if I have to.

Thanks in advance. Below is my (very badly) written code. Most of it is modified from a previous form we had..... (some info removed for privacy)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Purcahse Order</title>
        <style>
            body { font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; background-color:#F2F2F2; min-width:800px; }
            table { font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; padding-bottom:30px;}
            h1 { margin-top:15px; padding-top:0px; }
            h2 { margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:10px; }
            hr { border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #AAAAAA; }
            input, textarea,select { font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#333333; }
            .Section1 { position:relative; width:950px; margin:0px auto; }
            .left-col { width:130px; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top;}
            .left-col-w { width:230px; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:top;}
            .pageno { width:100px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;}
            .lineno { width:100px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;}
            .productcodeno { width:110px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;}
            .descriptionofgoods { width:250px; vertical-align:top;}
            .claimamount { width:150px; vertical-align:top; text-align:right;}
            .qty { width:50px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;}
            .float-left { float:left; position:relative; margin-right:50px; }
            .clear { clear:both; }
            .x-small { font-size:11px; color:#777777; }
            .footer { text-align:center; font-size:11px; color:#777777; }
        </style>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getClaimNumber.js"></script>


        <!-- Disable the Enter key from submitting the form -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               textboxes = $("input:text");

               if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                  $(textboxes).keypress(checkForEnter);
               } else {
                  $(textboxes).keydown(checkForEnter);
               }

               function checkForEnter(event) {
                  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                     currentTextboxNumber = textboxes.index(this);

                     if (textboxes[currentTextboxNumber + 1] != null) {
                       nextTextbox = textboxes[currentTextboxNumber + 1];
                       nextTextbox.select();
                  }

                     event.preventDefault();
                     return false;
                  }
               }
            }); 
        </script>
        <!-- Display the calendar on the datepicker id'd fields -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- Validate Form -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#claim_form").validate();
            });
        </script>

    <script>function getClaimNumber() {
    var getclaimNumber = //whatever they are using currently to get the Claim Number
                      // They're probably not putting it into a variable now, just assigning
                      // it somewhere, but since you're going to need it twice
                      // put it into a variable for resuse.
    // Do whatever you need to here to put it where it was going before.
    $('#GetClaimNumber').text(GetclaimNumber);
} </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class=Section1> 

          <h1><center>***********</center></h1>

            <h2>Purchase/Work Order<h2></center>
            <hr size=2 width="100%" align=center />

            <form action="./sent.php" method="post" name="claim_form" id="claim_form">
                <center><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="800px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Date:</td>
                            <td><? echo date('Y-m-d') ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Store Name:</td>
                            <td>                        
                                <?
                                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '936200');
                                    if (!$con)
                                      {
                                      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                      }

                                    mysql_select_db("DB", $con);

                                    $sql="SELECT * FROM StoreMaster ORDER BY HostID ";

                                    $result = mysql_query($sql);


                                    echo "<select name='store' class='required' onchange='getClaimNumber()'>";
                                    echo "<option></option>";

                                      echo "<option value='Service Centre'>Centre</option>";
                                      echo "<option value='Fishers Accademy'>Accademy</option>";
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                      {
                                      echo "<option value='$row[Name]'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
                                      }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                    mysql_close($con);
                                ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="sendto" id="sendto" value="" />
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Department:</td>
                            <td>
                                <?
                                    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
                                    if (!$con)
                                      {
                                      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                                      }

                                    mysql_select_db("database", $con);

                                    $sql="SELECT * FROM DeptMaster WHERE Code IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ORDER BY Code";

                                    $result = mysql_query($sql);


                                    echo "<select name='dept' class='required'>";
                                    echo "<option></option>";
                                    echo "<option value='Other'>Other</option>";

                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                      {
                                      echo "<option value='$row[Name]'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
                                      }
                                    echo "</select>";
                                    mysql_close($con);
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="left-col">Staff Members Name:</td>
                            <td><input name="claimedby" class='required' id="claimedby" type="text"></input></td>
                            <td class="left-col">PO Number:</td>   
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></center>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span id="displayClaimNumber"></span>

                <h2><center>Supplier Information</h2>
                <center><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="800px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Supplier:</td>
                            <td><input name="suppliername" class='required' type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Phone:</td>
                            <td><input name="supplierphone"type="text"></td>
                            <td class="left-col">Fax:</td>
                            <td><input name="supplierfax"type="text"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-col">Address:</td>
                            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="supplieraddress" class="required" style="width:560px"></textarea></center></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></center>

                <script>$("ponumber").text</script>                     

                <center><h3> Please supply the following and charge to the above account </h3></center>
                <center><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="2" width="800px">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>                           
                            <th>Desctiption/Items</th>
                            <th>Hours Worked</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    while ($i <= 7) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "  <input type='hidden' name='claimline" . $i . "' value='$i'></input>";
                        echo "  <td align='center'><input class='lineno' name='lineno$i' type='text' maxlength='10'></td>";
                        echo "  <td align='center'><input class='descriptionofgoods' name='descriptionofgoods$i' type='text'></td>";
                        echo "  <td align='center'><input class='qty' name='qty$i' type='text' maxlength='5'></td>";
                        echo "  <td align='center'>$ <input class='claimamount' name='claimamount$i' type='text'></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table></center>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <center><p>Authorised By:
      <input name="desc8" type="text" id="desc8" size="50">
       <input name="desc8" type="text" id="desc8" size="50">
    (name)</p>
    <p>Signed: ___________________________</p>
    <p>(Hard copy must contain a signiture)</p>
    <p><strong>PLEASE RETURN A COPY OF THIS DOCUMENT WITH YOUR INVOICE FOR PAYMENT</strong></p></center>

                <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send &raquo;">
                <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Clear">
                <input name="Print" type="submit" onclick="dlookup" value="Print">
            </form>
            <hr />

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: added more code to try to make sence

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a button. You just need to pick an element on the page to assign the value to. You can do anything, including a `<p>`, `<span>`, etc. and use jQuery to assign the `text()` value from what gets sent from the `getClaimNumber()`.

Here's documentation for the `text()` method.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

**Update**

If you have an element on your page similar to `<span id="displayClaimNumber"></span>`, then you'll want to add the following code to your javascript:

```
function getClaimNumber() {
    var claimNumber = //whatever they are using currently to get the Claim Number
                      // They're probably not putting it into a variable now, just assigning
                      // it somewhere, but since you're going to need it twice
                      // put it into a variable for resuse.
    // Do whatever you need to here to put it where it was going before.
    $('#displayClaimNumber').text(claimNumber);
}
```

If you need any more help, I'm going to need to see some code.